# Sankey Diagram, I want to show larger values in the bottom and smaller values on top

Tags: reactjs, charts, observable, sankey-diagram, react-google-charts

I want to achieve this graph below.

[image]

So far I have tried the following approaches:
Please please help me out. Any help would be highly appreciated! I just need to invert the positions of Hired and Rejected bars.

1. React Google Graphs - Sankey Diagram:

---

### https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-payne-s62zd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

### [image]
2) Observable HQ Sankey Diagram of Parallel Sets

### https://observablehq.com/d/1c49d550b2281f49

[image]

Comment: You can add your code in a codesandbox, it'll be easier for others to help.

Comment: I have attached the Sandbox as well as Observable HQ Link